# Unable to open nested entry 'WEB-INF/lib/example.jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have exicutable war file to run, I was deleted the one .jar file from WEB-INF/lib folder. Again added the same jar file into the same path but it was unable to run the war file it's getting below error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to
>   get nested archive for entry
>   WEB-INF/lib/test-cts-chk-query-rest-app-1.0.5/com/testcorp/cts/chk/query/rest/app/ClearinghouseQueryRESTController.class
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:70)
>     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:49)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open nested jar file
>   'WEB-INF/lib/test-cts-chk-query-rest-app-1.0.5/com/testcorp/cts/chk/query/rest/app/ClearinghouseQueryRESTController.class'
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:254)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:239)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:103)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open
>   nested entry
>   'WEB-INF/lib/test-cts-chk-query-rest-app-1.0.5/com/testcorp/cts/chk/query/rest/app/ClearinghouseQueryRESTController.class'.
>   It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without
>   compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable
>   jar file  at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:262)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:250)
>     ... 6 more

Is there any way to solve this on gradle project?

Comment: some time i face this type problem ...........
to solve this problem  i just recompile full project  ....
or delete target folder and re-run my maven project ...........

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you have a gradle project then you don't need to add external Jar you can write a gradle script to use that jar/class files in your program.

Second thing if you have just removed and added jar in the Lib directory You need to clean and build the project once.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get nested archive for entry

The jar file is not executable.

---

You can use the following.

Build a jar using spring bootJar task. It is by default enabled, though just to make sure Gradle builds jar using spring bootJar task.

```
bootJar { enabled true }
```

Disable the jfxJar task.

```
jfxJar { enabled false }
```

Provide bootJar output path to jfxAppOutputDir and also provide Spring boot JarLauncher as mainClass.

```
jfx {
    mainClass = 'org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher'

    jfxAppOutputDir = "${buildDir.path}/libs"
}
```

[enter link description here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html)